# Is it Possible to Add Email Selection Button in default mfmailcomposeviewcontroller for Selecting Multiple emails?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I am using iOS Native code and I want this kind of Functionality is it possible to Add Plus(+) button on TO Section of Email?if Yes then Can I implement the contact app Look and Feel here and Grab the Email id? Please need some suggestion how can i achieve this kind of Functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, i think there is not native api for Grab the Email in that way,

Here are some custom libraries,

- [TITokenFieldView](https://github.com/enriquez/TITokenFieldView),
- [JSTokenField](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField)
- [TTPickerTextFieldDemo](https://github.com/shayne/TTPickerTextFieldDemo)

Comment: can't i add Custom UIButton to MFMailViewController?

Comment: No,The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.[apple doc ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot and in iOS 7 is by default as well so 1 good things comes up.